# how to search for two specific words in a text file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am having a text file in which I need to search for the words 'insert' and 'condition'.

- When i encounter 'insert' and then 'condition' I should append the line in a list.
- If I encounter two 'insert' words it should skip that 'insert' and move forward to find the next 'insert' and 'condition' pair.

```
                                 ***code***
word='insert'
word1='condition'
i=[]
c=[]
with open(filename,'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if word in line:
            i.append(line)
        if word in line: 
        ## here i am searching for next insert before condition.
        ## if i get insert before condition,i pop the previous inserted line 
        ## and append the new one
            i.pop()
            i.append(line)
        if word1 in line:
            c.append(line)

print c
print i

                      ***code ends***
```

***input text sample*** 
insert hello1 
condition yes it is hello1

insert hello2 
insert hello3 
insert hello4 
condition yes it is hello4

***sample output*** 
Here in lists I dont want insert hello2 and insert hello3 since they dont have a condition. considering 2 lists i[] and c[],I want the lists to contain

i=['insert hello1,'insert hello4'] c=['condition yes it is hello1','condition yes it is hello4']

Comment: If there is an "insert condition" in the line, you must add whole the line to the  list?

Comment: yes the whole line should be added to the list. example insert_job : op_fe-oax_model is the line.when i find "insert_job" i should append the whole line into the list

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is not clear to me and you didn't respond to my comment. If this is not the program that you looking for, please leave a comment and let me to modify it.*

**input.txt:(sample)**

> insert insert hello1
>
> insert condition hello2
>
> insert condition condition 2
>
> condition insert hello3
>
> insert

**The program:**

```
substring = "insert condition"
myList=[]

with open("input.txt",'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if (substring in line):
            myList.append(line)

print myList
```

**output:**

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
['insert condition hello2\n', 'insert condition condition 2\n']
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry Abraham this isn't what I'm asking,assume the text file as                               insert_job:op_fe-_oax model

Comment: That's OK, I'll delete it. but what is _insert_job:op_fe-_oax_ ?

Comment: Sorry Abraham this isn't what I'm asking,assume the text file as                               **(1)insert_job:op_fe-_oax model  \n    date: 1/1993 \n condition:successful  \n (2)insert_job:op_fe-abs_model                                                                                  date:05/1995   \n (3)insert_job:op_fe-xyz_model **.                             In this case i would like to replace (2) with (3) insert_job because after that i again encounter another insert job rather than a condition

Comment: its just a normal text file op_fe-oax,nothing like a keyword or variable,just a simple text file

Comment: @user3645395 Can you please add a simple input and your required sample output to the question?